# Как из ФИО сделать урезанную версию?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Помогите решить задачку. Не силен в регулярных выражениях.
Имеется на входе - "Фамилия Имя Отчество" или "Фамилия Имя" могут быть оба варианта. 
На выходе нужно получить "Фамилия И.О." или "Фамилия И." соответственно

Comment: Регулярные выражения тут вообще не нужны.

Comment: почему? меньше кода

Comment: Потому что регулярные выражения совсем не для этого. Тут нужно просто обрезать все, кроме первой буквы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нужно именно регуляркой, то как-то так:

```
$str = 'Фамилия Имя Отчество';

echo preg_replace('~\h\K(\p{Lu})\p{Ll}+~u', '$1.', $str);
```

Answer (score -1):

Можно на php

Пример:

```php
$FIO = "Фамилия Имя Отчество";

$FIOarr = explode(' ', $FIO);
$count = count($FIOarr);

$Surname = $FIOarr[0];
$Name = iconv_substr($FIOarr[1], 0, 1) . ".";
if (array_key_exists(2, $FIOarr)){
    $Patronymic = ' ' . iconv_substr($FIOarr[2], 0, 1) . ".";
} else {
    $Patronymic = "";
}

$FIOnew = $Surname . ' ' . $Name . $Patronymic;

echo $FIOnew;
```